# Page not found after deploying on tomcat using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Each time i make a new project and run it i get error not found

and here is the console log :

```
Sep 10, 2015 11:58:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_60/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_60/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_60/lib/i386;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\oracle\ora92\bin;C:\Program Files\Oracle\jre\1.3.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Oracle\jre\1.1.8\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files\Seagate Software\NOTES\;C:\Program Files\Seagate Software\NOTES\DATA\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;F:\Sources\eclipse;;.
Sep 10, 2015 11:58:31 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 10, 2015 11:58:31 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 10, 2015 11:58:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1545 ms
Sep 10, 2015 11:58:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 10, 2015 11:58:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.64
Sep 10, 2015 11:58:32 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [156] milliseconds.
Sep 10, 2015 11:58:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor F:\Java projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\conf\Catalina\localhost\Courses.xml
Sep 10, 2015 11:58:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Courses' did not find a matching property.
Sep 10, 2015 11:58:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Sep 10, 2015 11:58:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor F:\Java projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\conf\Catalina\localhost\Courses.xml has finished in 3,819 ms
Sep 10, 2015 11:58:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor F:\Java projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\conf\Catalina\localhost\CoursesPro.xml
Sep 10, 2015 11:58:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:CoursesPro' did not find a matching property.
Sep 10, 2015 11:58:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor F:\Java projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\conf\Catalina\localhost\CoursesPro.xml has finished in 33 ms
Sep 10, 2015 11:58:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor F:\Java projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\conf\Catalina\localhost\CoursesTest.xml
Sep 10, 2015 11:58:36 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:CoursesTest' did not find a matching property.
Sep 10, 2015 11:58:37 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(F:\Java projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\CoursesTest\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Sep 10, 2015 11:58:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Sep 10, 2015 11:58:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor F:\Java projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\conf\Catalina\localhost\CoursesTest.xml has finished in 3,721 ms
Sep 10, 2015 11:58:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 10, 2015 11:58:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 10, 2015 11:58:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 8231 ms**
```

Comment: Does your web application have jar named as `servlet-api.jar` inside `WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: no it does not contain this file

Answer (score 1):

You're deploying on tomcat.  The default things to check are:

1. is your application displayed as 'running' in the manager

If displayed as failed, it failed, and there should be something in the logs.  Probably your logging is misconfigured.
If not even displayed, you don't have a web.xml or context.xml file

2. does your application look sane in the deploy directory

According to your logs it's at `F:\Java projects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\CoursesTest`.  Check there if WEB-INF/web.xml is present, and if the file that you're trying to reach is actually in that folder.

3. are you using a correct url?

If you're just trying to open the root url of your application, and there is no index or default servlet to handle it, you can get this error.  Other urls might work though.
*